# SSIS Multicast - Wait for one fork to finish before executing next fork

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS Mulitcast object that splits my flow into 2 paths.

In the first path I insert the flow into another database.

In the second path I update the rows of the flow to show that they were inserted.

I need a way to make one path wait until the other path has finished.  (So I can handle any insert errors and not update the rows for those that were errors.)

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked into this more and here is the answer I came up with:

On each output of the multicast I put a sort operation, then I join them using a MergeJoin operation.  After that I do a SQL Update using an OLE DB command on the items that don't have an error value from the mergejoin.

Comment: Just what I needed! I was trying to solve this problem using a merge all, but it did not work. I have 2 SCDs, and I wanted that one is executed after one is finished. Got around it by doing a multitask, 2 sorts, a merge join, and another sort after that to remove duplicates.

Comment: Could you detail on the subject ?, I am new to the management of SSIS and I have a similar problem.

Comment: Can you add more context around why that would work along with a visual if possible? I have the same issue I am trying to resolve for but the answer here isn't very clear to me.

Comment: @ItalianStallion4215 - Unfortunately this answer is over a decade old.  I don't recall the SSIS Project that this was for.  I seem to recall that maybe I used the output of the first branch for the merge join into the second branch.  Since the first branch's output was input to the second branch, the second branch had to wait for the first branch to finish.

Answer (score 3):

If you know roughly how long it will take for one fork to finish, you could use an OLE DB Command on your second fork. Type in "waitfor delay '00:00:15'" to cause the server to wait 15 seconds before going to the next step.

[image: Waitfor]

Comment: Please remove the whitespace in your post.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in SSIS. You can only enforce precedence constraints (i.e. enforce order of the run) at the Control Flow level.

Answer (score 1):

In that case I would not use a multicast but a regular dataflow so that one doesn't start before the first one completed successfully

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to actually use a Script component.  From there you can manage do the insert and update sequentially with try catch blocks.